# How to refresh tooltip of a DataGridView cell while it's shown?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, tooltip

I am trying to refresh the tooltip of a `DataGridViewCell` without leaving and reentering the cell with the cursor.

I assign a new value to `ToolTipText` property of the cell, but while the tooltip is showing, changing `ToolTipText` property of column doesn't have any impact on the tooltip which is showing.

This is a snapshot of a server application of mine. People can join and you can see their ping:

[image]

I want to be able to see how the ping changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the `ToolTip` of a cell is showing, changing the `ToolTipText` of the cell doesn't change the tool tip text automatically. To change it, you can handle `CellToolTipChanged` event of `DataGridView` to detect a change in `ToolTipText` of a cell. Then you can check make the `DataGridView` shows the new text in tooltip using such code:

```
private void dgv_CellToolTipTextChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    var grid = (DataGridView)sender;
    var toolTipControl = grid.GetType().GetField("toolTipControl",
            System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic |
            System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(grid);
    var activated = (bool)toolTipControl.GetType()
        .GetProperty("Activated").GetValue(toolTipControl);
    if (activated)
    {
        var cell = grid[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex];
        var ActivateToolTip = typeof(DataGridView).GetMethod("ActivateToolTip",
                System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);
        ActivateToolTip.Invoke(grid,
            new object[] { true, cell.ToolTipText, e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex });
    }
}
```

**Example**

As an example, I changed the `ToolTipText` of a cell in a timer to get the following result:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].ToolTipText = DateTime.Now.ToString();
}
```

[image]

Comment: So above you get the field named "toolTipControl", where is that set?

Comment: I just handled `CellToolTipTextChanged` event of `DataGridView`. The rest of code is finding the internal tooltip control of `DataGridView` using reflection and making it to show new tooltip text.

Comment: Because when I try to get the field all I get is `null`. I think I'm missing something.

Comment: Just create a simple example like I did and use exactly these codes, the screenshot has been taken from a real execution of the code.

Comment: Figured out the problem. I made a custom class for the purpose of setting the DoubleBuffer property to true. Apparently that's why it could't find the toolTipControl field. Anyway thanks so much for your help.